# Dynamic elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to put two elements side by side, but the button element should take as much space as it requires to keep all text in one line. The h1 element should wrap to the second line if necessary based on how much space the button element takes.

Basically, I want to support dynamically changing text lengths, without defining static widths for h1 or button element. Is this possible to achieve?

Link to my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npa6a4hn/3/).

```css
section {
  width: 600px;
}

h1 {
  float: left;
  /* Width can't be used here, cos the texts are different length at different times */
  width: 400px;
}

button {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Header should wrap to second if needed, based on how much button element uses space -->
  <h1>Dynamic text that should wrap to second line if needed, because the text is sometimes pretty long</h1>
  <!-- Button should use as much space as possible to fit the text on one line-->
  <button>Dynamic button text</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Prime example of where [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) comes in.

Comment: [I guess you want `<wbr>`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)

Comment: if the button is to take up as much space as possible, you'd want to explicitly set it to do so.

Comment: So this then - https://jsfiddle.net/p8tdekos/

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the flexbox solution. Add `display: flex;` to the container element (in this case, the `<section>`) and `flex-grow: 1` to the heading - this makes the heading expand to fill the available space.

One side-effect is that the button will be stretched vertically by default (to match the height of the heading). You can account for this by explicitly setting the button's `height`, or by wrapping the button in a `<div>`. If you do that, the new `<div>` will be stretched vertically, but the button will remain its normal size.

```
section {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  flex-grow:1;
  width: 400px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Here it is in action in a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tomhazledine/xnuLx227/) (I've added the extra `<div>` around the button).

Comment: Almost what I wanted, but I couldn't get the button to behave normally by the div or height solution. Paulie_D's solution behaved exactly as I wanted.